# Create a schema with the name passed by variable in java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm creating schemas in postgresql by a class in java with jdbc. It seems to work fine but I need a function to create the schemas, i was wondering if its possible to Create a schema with the name passed by variable... This is my class CreateSchema:

is it possible?

```
String sql = "CREATE SCHEMA centro";
```

in this line "centro" like a variable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        System.out.println("Creating Schema...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "CREATE SCHEMA centro";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Schema created successfully...");
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: If `string schemaName = "centro"`, you are asking if something like `String sql ="CREATE SCHEMA " +schemaName`.can be done?

Comment: yeah, that's my question

Comment: That's your answer then :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can connect to postgresql without get a database name to your BASE_URL. And about your question. Yes you can create or drop database by concatenating SQL statement to given name: `"CREATE DATABASE " + databseName`.

So your code could be as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        System.out.println("Creating Schema...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String dbName = "centro"; // or get it from command line
        String sql = "CREATE SCHEMA " + dbName;
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Schema created successfully...");
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: :(  give the error : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SCHEMAnameEschema "

Comment: It seems that you forget space after word SCHEMA. Is not it?

Comment: However instead you can use this statement also: `"CREATE DATABASE " + dbName`

Comment: oh it works! it was the space before the schema, what a dummie, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then you're just after simple String concatenation.

So, for example, if you run the application from the command line and supply the first argument as "centro", the code would be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //all your other stuff

    String sql = "CREATE SCHEMA " + args[0]; // -> "CREATE SCHEMA centro"
}
```

Or if you want to specify it somewhere in the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //all your other stuff

   String schema = "centro";

   String sql = "CREATE SCHEMA " + schema; // -> "CREATE SCHEMA centro"
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, gives me the error org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SCHEMAnameS

Comment: @GabrielaRdz you forgot the space between `CREATE SCHEMA` and your schema name.